# Como obter a resposta de um activity chamado de uma classe ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, android-activity

Tenho a activity `ActLevantamento`, onde criei um layout personalizado utilizando uma classe herdada de `ArrayAdapter`, classe `AtributoArrayAdapter`.

Neste layout personalizado, eu tenho um botão, e na chamada deste botão eu chamo a activity `ActPlantaEncontrada`. A ideia é editar/inserir valores na `ActPlantaEncontrada` e retornar este valores para o meu item da `AtributoArrayAdapter`. Se fosse uma activity chamando outra activity eu poderia utilizar o `startActivityForResult()` e obter o retorno no método `onActivityResult()`, porém não é possível.

Como fazer isso?

Abaixo trecho da classe AtributoArrayAdapter onde chamo a activity para editar/inserir os valores. A edição ainda não está implementada.

```
 Intent it = new Intent(context, ActPlantaEncontrada.class);
                    it.putExtra(Constants.PARAM_PERFIL_NOME, avh.stPerfilNome);
                    getContext().startActivity(it);
```

Comment: A dificuldade surge porque você está a atribuir uma responsabilidade ao ArrayAdapter que ele não deveria ter. Lembre-se que um adapter só tem uma responsabilidade: servir de intermediário entre uma fonte de dados(array) e a sua representação visual(listview)

Comment: Realmente! Efetuei o tratamento do evento na própria activity onde construo o layout dinâmico. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Em programação quando algo que queremos fazer fica complicado normalmente é porque estamos a seguir uma abordagem errada.

Comment: Sempre bom um segundo olhar para clarear onde estamos errando.